# Power BI Measure - Summarize distinct values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to find the sum for defective effort but I need it to only sum distinct WorkItemId where Links.TargetWorkItem.WorkItemId is not blank

Measures I currently have:

Defective Effort = CALCULATE(SUM('Work items with direct links'[Effort]),NOT(ISBLANK('Work items with direct links'[Links.TargetWorkItem.WorkItemId])))

For the Sum in the table below (and in the chart) I am wanting the total to be 31 not 35, The Effort for ID 10829 is Getting counted twice

[image: Chart]

[image: Table]

Comment: Can you share some sample data and desired outputs?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having turned out to be the relationship between two tables.  Created a table with only one entry for each sprint # then tied all the tables back to that table with a 1:many instead of many:many.  This resolved the problem.

Thanks everyone for your help.